# Problem on formula field?

Tags: formula-field

i am trying to create formula field in my custom object this formula field needs to return the text datatype in advanced formula i took text field that text having numbers like 1234 when record creating formula field will update like 1234 but i need like this 1,234 how i can achieve.
[image]

Comment: If you want the formula to return a number with the appropriate punctuation then have the formula return a number type not text.

Comment: agree with Eric. Besides that, the screenshot you pasted does not seem related at all with the question you have..?

Comment: Thank you for responding... i need to return my formula filed like this lastname , 1,234 but my userid data type text thats why only i am taking isnumber to convert number form

Answer (score 1):

The number data type is not just about putting commas every three digits. It's actually locale aware, so that users using other standard number formats, like 123 45,50 (123,45.50) will see the value in the format they're accustomed to. There's no native formula operator that duplicates this functionality. You could build a formula to add the appropriate commas and so on, but depending on how many digits you want to support, it gets a bit complicated due to the limits of the language. One possible scenario might go like this:

```
TRIM(
  IF(LEN(Last_Name__c)>15, MID(LPAD(Last_Name__c,18,' '),  1, 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(Last_Name__c)>12, MID(LPAD(Last_Name__c,18,' '),  4, 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(Last_Name__c)> 9, MID(LPAD(Last_Name__c,18,' '),  7, 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(Last_Name__c)> 6, MID(LPAD(Last_Name__c,18,' '), 10, 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(Last_Name__c)> 3, MID(LPAD(Last_Name__c,18,' '), 13, 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(Last_Name__c)> 0, MID(LPAD(Last_Name__c,18,' '), 16, 3)      ,'')
) &
  userId__c
```

Keep in mind that users used to other types of formatting will not see their expected native number format.

Comment: Last_Name__c  & "," 
 &
 TRIM(
  IF(LEN(userid__c)>15, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c,18,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)>12, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c,15,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 9, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c,12,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 6, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c, 9,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 3, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c, 6,' '), 3) & ',','') &
  IF(LEN(userid__c)> 0, LEFT(LPAD(userid__c, 3,' '), 3)      ,'')
)

Comment: but output coming work lastname= test , userid = 1234 means formula field returns test,1,123 but actual result needs  test,1,234

Comment: @hariP It needed a bit of a touch-up, so here's a new version. I tested this one in my org first.